# Restrict UIWebview to certain pages

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I am trying to create a simple ipad app with a UIWebview that displays a form that a customer can fill in.. what i want to do is restrict the app so that it only allows the user to navigate to certain addresses.. (i.e. either something that allows the user to go to a specific address.. OR something that checks for specific keywords and allows/blocks them as appropriate..)

Could someone please show me how its done..

NB: its basically a googledocs form and i dont want to let the user navigate away from it.. (the user could easily click away and go elsewhere)

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the class that is your `UIWebViewDelegate` you can use something like this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

    //Check for your own url. You can use more advanced checking techniques of course :)
    NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"http://www.yourUrl.com"];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

to determine whether the UIWebView can load a given web page. Although that would mean knowing exactly which pages are allowed (if there are many this might not be convenient).

Comment: ive read about this.. could you by any chance show me how to use it.. or maybe if u know of a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: You set some class as the delegate of the UIWebView, and implement this method. Whenever the UIWebView wants to load a request it calls this method on the delegate. In that method you look at the NSURLRequest (request) url, [request URL], and see whether you want to authorize it or not, if you do your return YES, if not, NO.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

Then check what is the URL that the UIWebView tires to load, and act consequently.

[UIWebViewDelegate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)