# Restricting the domain/url of a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm trying to include an online form in my application using a **UIWebView**, and I noticed that once the user finishes the form, s/he can navigate to different addresses. Is there any way I can restrict the domain/url access of a webkit?

(This used to be possible using UIWebView **example**: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673116/restrict-uiwebview-to-certain-pages‌](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673116/restrict-uiwebview-to-certain-pages%E2%80%8C) but it's now deprecated)

Answer (score 4):

WKWebView can utilize the [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview) to restrict navigation.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        if let url = navigationAction.request.URL {

            if url == permittedUrl {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            }
        }
}
```